# VBA - Incorrect graphing code

Tags: vba, excel, graph

First of all, thank you for all the help in the past, this site is a blessing, and you all are saints.  Now down to business

I am having trouble with one set of my test data, the other graphs correctly, however, this set of data is causing my graphs to look wrong.  I think I found the problem, but I am unsure on how to fix it.  When my code creates the range to graph, it is not grabbing the right range due to a mathematical error.  For reference, `DataLength = 102`, and this is what the graph and a portion of the data looks like.[image: graph]  I need to graph to `"CZ"` but it is only going to D because `fRemainder = 0` And here is the out of wack code.

```
    Dim iAlpha As Integer, fAlpha As Integer
    Dim iRemainder As Integer, fRemainder As Integer
    Dim ConvertToLetter As String
    Dim fConvertToLetter As String

    iAlpha = Int((DataLength) / 26) '26 for the letters
    fAlpha = Int((DataLength + 2) / 26) 'for the average and sd functions, since they start at C not A
    iRemainder = DataLength - (iAlpha * 26)
    fRemainder = DataLength + 2 - (fAlpha * 26)
    If iAlpha > 0 Then
       ConvertToLetter = Chr(iAlpha + 64)
    End If
    If iRemainder > 0 Then
       ConvertToLetter = ConvertToLetter & Chr(iRemainder + 64)
    End If
    If fAlpha > 0 Then
       fConvertToLetter = Chr(fAlpha + 64)
    End If
    If fRemainder > 0 Then
       fConvertToLetter = fConvertToLetter & Chr(fRemainder + 64)
    End If
```

And for additional reference, this is the actual graphing code is.  The first line offsets from `"C13"`, however the cell changes with each grouping, ie. `"C13" "C49" "C85"` etc.

```
ActiveCell.Offset(-7, -2).Select
ActiveCell.Range("A1:" & fConvertToLetter & "4").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
ActiveCell.Activate
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select
With ActiveChart
    .ChartType = xlLine
    .Axes(xlCategory).Select
    .HasTitle = True
    .ChartTitle.Text = Range("B" & (12 * x - 5)).Value
End With
With ActiveChart.Parent
     .Top = 153 * x + 12.75 * 2 ' reposition cells are 12.75 high and there are 36 cells between
     .Left = 50   ' reposition
End With
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are different ways to define the ranges used for charts.  In the example below, I show 2 ways, one to make the initial chart, and then another based upon adding a new series to the chart. It is best to remove statements like `selection` and `.select` that the macro recorder uses, and instead define range variables.  These range variables can be fine-tuned using the `.offset` function as needed.  Step through the code as I show in the animated .gif to help understand how it works, and then adjust as needed for your application.

[image]

```
Option Explicit
Sub chartRange()
Dim r As Range, chObj As ChartObject, ser As Series
Set r = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:B5")
Set chObj = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Add(Left:=100, Width:=375, Top:=75, Height:=225)
    With chObj
    .chart.ChartType = xlXYScatterLines
    .chart.SetSourceData Source:=r
    End With
    If MsgBox("Plot y2 also?", vbYesNo) Then
      Set ser = chObj.chart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
      Set r = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A5")
      ser.XValues = r
      ser.Values = r.Offset(0, 2)
      ser.Name = "y2"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: how would you recommend editing my graphing code, because I am a bit at a loss here.  The range that I need graphed will never be finite, and changes with each use.  I need to ensure that it works with an array of data sets.

Comment: Here's one example. Set r = Range("A1").end(xlDown) is one way to define a range for a column of continuous data having unknown length. If you take some time to learn about the range function I think it will help you quite a bit both now and in the long run

Comment: Correction: Set r = Range("A1").end(xlDown) only gets you to the bottom of the continuous range.  To define a continuous range from A1 to its bottom, use Set r = Range("A1") as one line of code and then in the next line Set r = Range(r, r.end(xlDown))