# VBA trying to change the bordercolors in columncluster chart

Tags: vba, excel, charts

i am trying to create a macro which automatically creates a chart with pre set layout but the part about the data series border colors and interior colors is not working can anybody help me out pls

```
Sub Macrochart()

         Dim myChart As ChartObject
         Dim mySeries As Series

         Set myChart = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Add(100, 50, 200, 200)

         With myChart

         .Chart.SetSourceData Source:=Selection
         .Chart.ChartType = xlColumnClustered
         .Chart.ApplyLayout (8)

         For Each mySeries In myChart.SeriesCollection
         With mySeries
                .Series.Border.LineStyle = xlSolid
                .Series.Border.Color = vbBlack
                .Series.Interior.Color = vbWhite

           End With
           Next
           End With

    End Sub
```

this is the macro ive been trying to use i am really new to vba so no real clue what i am doing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This modification of your code worked for me. As it stands, it will only work if your current selection does in fact select source data properly.  It's better to define a range object that defines the source data. Let me know if you have questions.

```
Sub Macrochart()
Dim myChart As ChartObject
Dim mySeries As Series
Set myChart = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Add(100, 50, 200, 200)
With myChart
.Chart.SetSourceData Source:=Selection
.Chart.ChartType = xlColumnClustered
.Chart.ApplyLayout (8)

 For Each mySeries In .Chart.SeriesCollection
  With mySeries
    .Border.LineStyle = xlSolid
    .Border.Color = vbBlack
    .Interior.Color = vbWhite
  End With
  Next
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: thank you so much haha started getting really frustrated

Comment: If you're question has been answered, please mark it as answered so others will know.  Otherwise, ask questions until you're satisfied.

Comment: is there away to ad x values per selection ?

Comment: .SeriesCollection(1).XValues :=Selection   id come up with that line i dont know if i can really use it and where to pu it

Comment: Yes, you can define x- and y- source data independently, that is you can set the .XValues as one range and the .Values as another range.  These lines of code would be used instead of your "setSourceData" line. Please see this link for some code that defines chart source data in 2 different ways; the second one does x- and y- source data independently  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45740266/vba-incorrect-graphing-code/45740826#45740826

Comment: There's a little check box at the upper left of each answer, right below the buttons used to rate the answers

Answer (score 0):

here is a rewrite with a test data range added (just delete the line after testing)

```
Sub Macrochart()

    ' fill test data
    ActiveSheet.Range("a1:b5") = Application.Transpose(Array(Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), Array(23, 45, 67, 33, 12)))

    Dim myChart As ChartObject
    Set myChart = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Add(100, 50, 200, 200)

    With myChart.Chart
'       .SetSourceData Source:=Selection        ' original posted code
        .SetSourceData Source:=Range("a1:b5")   ' test range
        .ChartType = xlColumnClustered
        .ApplyLayout (8)
    End With

    Dim mySeries As Series
    For Each mySeries In myChart.Chart.SeriesCollection
        With mySeries
            .Border.LineStyle = xlSolid
            .Border.Color = vbBlack
            .Interior.Color = vbWhite
        End With
    Next

End Sub
```